# Symfony3 – Form submission with clearMissing – nullified properties always – how to fix this?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm using "Symfony ~3.3".

If i send in request only `bar` property (without `zyx` because i don't need to change it), i get error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Foo::setZyx() must be of the type string, null given, called in /full/path/to/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 636

My question is simple: why `clearMissing` parameter is ignored and how to achive editing only selected properties?

---

Some code here:

Controller:

```php
class FooController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Patch("/foo/{id}", requirements={"id": "\d+"})
     *
     * @Rest\RequestParam(name="bar", nullable=true)
     * @Rest\RequestParam(name="zyx", nullable=true)
     *
     * @param int          $id
     * @param ParamFetcher $pf
     *
     * @return Response
     *
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException
     */
    public function editAction(int $id, ParamFetcher $pf) : Response
    {
        $foo = $this->repository->find($id);
        if (!$foo) throw $this->createNotFoundException();

        $form = $this->createForm(FooType::class, $foo);
        $form->submit($pf->all(), false); // <––––– HERE

        if (!$form->isSubmitted() || !$form->isValid())
            throw new BadRequestHttpException($this->view($form->getErrors(true))->getData());

        $foo = $form->getData();
        $this->em->merge($foo);
        $this->em->flush();

        return $this->responder->respond($foo);
    }
}
```

Doctrine entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min="3", max="190")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190)
     */
    private $bar;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min="3")
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $zyx;

    public function __construct(string $bar, string $zyx)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
        $this->zyx = $zyx;
    }

    public function getBar() : string { return $this->bar; }
    public function getZyx() : string { return $this->zyx; }

    public function setBar(string $v) { $this->bar = $v; }
    public function setZyx(string $v) { $this->zyx = $v; }
}
```

Form type:

```
class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('bar', TextType::class)
            ->add('zyx', TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'      => Foo::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            // todo Better way to workaround constructor requirements?
            'empty_data'      => new Foo('_', '_'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

Changing controller like this will solve issue.. but.. that's really ugly and decreases maintainability. Is here any other way?

```php
class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function editAction(int $id, ParamFetcher $pf) : Response
    {
        $foo = ...;

        $form = $this->createForm(FooType::class, $foo);

        $submit = [];
        $bar = $pf->get('bar');
        $zyx = $pf->get('zyx');
        if (!empty($bar)) $submit['bar'] = $bar;
        if (!empty($zyx)) $submit['zyx'] = $zyx;
        $form->submit($submit, false);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: nullified - I like that ..  "I'm gonna nullify you!" .. lol

Comment: yes, you can use `array_filter()` on your `$submit` array and remove it.

Comment: Oh, so simple! Thanks a lot for this. With filtering – works as expected.
Write as an answer?

Comment: I just updated my answer, you should make sure `array_filter` removes what you want, it can remove `'0'` and `0` as well as `false`, but you can supply a custom callback if you need it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um this doesn't work?

```
      public function __construct(string $bar, string $zyx = ""){
          if( strlen( $zyx  ) > 0 )  $this->zyx = $zyx;
          $this->zyx = $zyx;
         ...
      }
```

If you felt inclined to cheat on the setter you could do this

```
  public function __set( $key, $value ){
      if( !method_exits( $this, '_'.$key ) ) throw new Exception('unknown method' );

      if( !empty( $value ) )  $this->'_'.$key( $value );

  }

  protected function  _setZyx(string $v) { $this->zyx = $v; }
```

Then when you call the setZyx() ( undefined ) it uses the magic set method that filters out empty values....  I don't use Symphony so I don't know if they check `method_exists()` etc..  I just thought it would be `fun`

***UPDATE***

Looking at your update you can do it this way too

```
    $submit = [];
    $submit['bar'] = $pf->get('bar');
    $submit['zyx'] = $pf->get('zyx');

    $submit = array_filter( $submit ); //you may need a custom callback,

    $form->submit($submit, false);
```

But it may be more maintainable that way, you could even extend `$form` class and override the submit function and bake it in that way.

I am not a symphony user ( so I don't know the convention for overriding stuff )  but personally I would do something like this after extending the $form class

```
  public function submit( $submit, $arg1, $filter = false ){
      //sorry not sure what the second arg is, but anyway

      if( $filter ){
          if( gettype( $filter ) == 'boolean' )
              $submit = array_filter( $submit );
          else
              $submit = array_filter( $submit, $filter );
      }

      parent::submit( $submit, $arg1 );
  }
```

Then it's backed into the class, and you can either call `true` or give it a closure to use as the filter, such as

```
    $form2->submit( $submit, false, function( $item ){
         return strlen( $item );
    });
```

You could also wrap it in another function inside a base controller or some helper class ( and pass $form to it ), then you don't need the code all over the place.

Comment: This will work in that case (need to allow null in getter/setter too).. but `zyx` (because of domain logic) cannot be `null` – it MUST be a string, always.
So, this is not a solution – entity then may be in invalid state.

Comment: Lol (-: No.

1. Symfony form will call `setZyx(null)`, but it needs a string. It will work only if i allow null: `setZyx(string $v = null)`

2. Empty string or null-value may run entity in inconsistent state – that is very bad for domain logic.

Comment: As of this experiments (see pt.1), i guess that SF really calls setter for `xyz` with `null`. Even if i use `$clearMissing = false`.

Comment: I could get around the setter using `__set()` it would be ugly though, PS I hate Doctrine, by the way.

Comment: This seems like a design issue, not one of logic.  Either you have zyx that is always required ( and you supply it ) or you don't.

Comment: Getting around with `__set()` has same meaning – entity cannot differ form from other code. Domain requirement: `$foo->setZyx(null)` must call an error, always.

Comment: Then what is the issue, when you don't send it ( it's null ) and you get an error.

Comment: I've added to question one solution that works – write a lots of boilerplate and duplicated code (meh..). Many properties – tons of lines this bad code.

Comment: About logic. I pass Foo entity from DB that already has valid state of all properties. Why SF call `setProp($value)` even if there is no named property in request? I think, this is bug or i'm using forms wrong..

Comment: Issue here simple: when i do not send `zyx`, it must be not set to entity at all. Entity guaranties that `zyx` already has valid state of it.

Comment: Yeah, i can use just `$form->submit(array_filter($pf->all()), false)`. For this usecase. Or pass a callback to custom filtering. That is maintainable solution, thank you.